# Is it possible to put conditions on the outtmpl option in youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm writing a Python script that will download all the videos from a text file of URLs. How can I make the program use different values in the outtmpl-option, depending on the attributes in each URL?

```
ydl_opts = {
'outtmpl': '%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s',
}
```

Basically, for each URL in the text file, I want to have the following logic:

If the URL is a playlist that has an uploader:

```
ydl_opts['outtmpl'] = '%(playlist)s/%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

If the URL is a playlist with NO uploader:

```
ydl_opts['outtmpl'] = '%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

If the URL is NOT a playlist but has an uploader:

```
ydl_opts['outtmpl'] = '%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

If the URL is NOT a playlist and has NO uploader:

```
ydl_opts['outtmpl'] = '%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

(I have currently solved the playlist-part in a very dumb way: i'm preprocessing the list of URLs by checking if any URL contains the word "playlist". I don't even know a dumb way to solve the uploader-part.)

Is there a generalized way to modify the outtmpl-option depending on the attributes of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other way than making a if/else statement and the add the wanted outtmpl to ydl_opts like this:

```
outtmpl = { '%(title)s.%(ext)s' }
ydl_opts.update()
```

or you just edit the ydl_opts['outtmpl'] like you did in your example.